# System.Diagnostics.Process unable to launch file from Mapped Drive in Windows Form App

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, system.diagnostics

I have an Windows App in VS2010 using VB.NET and .NET 3.5.  It is formless and very simple, it will "launch" the contents of the clipboard assuming it is a string.  Note this is NOT ASP.NET and nothing to do with a web app.

Here is the heart of the code:

```
Dim proc As New Process()
proc.StartInfo.FileName = strClipboard
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
proc.Start()
```

For years it has worked just fine.  If there user has a file path, say "c:\temp\file.txt" saved as a string in the system clipboard they could run this app (typeically by assigning it to a mouse button) and it would be just like going to Start>Run, pasting the text in, and hitting Enter.

Recently something has changed with our systems.  Not sure what but I suspect it has something with all of our new server configurations changing and/or group policies because now it will not work on any mapped drive.

For example this works just fine:

```
C:\Temp\test.txt
```

but not this:

```
L:\Temp\test.txt
```

with L being a mapped drive on our local file server.  The error I get from the exception is simply that it cannot find the file:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was caught
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Message=The system cannot find the path specified
  NativeErrorCode=3
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at VS10_Launch_Clipboard.Launch_Clipboard.Main() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VS10_Launch_Clipboard\VS10_Launch_Clipboard\Module1.vb:line 21
  InnerException:
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ernie

Comment: Try to \\000.000.00.00\temp\test.txt. I mean try with IP. Or server name \\myserver\\test.txt

Comment: Drive mappings are a per-user property.  So if it was put on the clipboard by a process than ran with a different user account then you'll have a problem.

Comment: @kostasch. Good suggestion thanks.  It does indeed work if I do full UNC so this works:  \\fsservername\Data\Temp\test.txt but L:\Temp\test.txt does NOT even though if I then copy/paste that exact string into start>run it works fine (this is all being done on my machine with the EXE save on my c drive).

Comment: @Ernie good for you. I  am happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it runs properly for me. The only way I could reproduce your error is by running it with an unmapped drive (Changed to z:\text.txt which is not mapped).

Make sure that the computer RUNNING the program has the specified mapped drive on their computer. Just because the program may reside on a server and the server has the required mapped drives, doesn't mean that the clients running the program have the same mapped drives.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas.  This is ALL running on my local machine with the EXE on my hard drive.  The only time the file server comes into play is when I try and string that is pointed at it like "L:\Temp\test.txt".  Everything else is on my c drive.